# How to import data from csv file to a list inside a dictionary "myDict" in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, set

```
myDict = {'Name':[],'Tribe':[],'Town':[],'Username':[]}
```

How to import data from CSV file into a list inside a dictionary `myDict` in python?

```
a.csv
Daniel,Bataknese,Indramayu,dan.iel
Melissa,Javanese,Jakarta,melissaaaa
Vicky,Bataknese,Jakarta,vic.ky
Winona,Javanese,Batam,weenonuhh
```

myDict should be like this:

```
myDict = {'Name': ['Daniel', 'Melissa', 'Vicky', 'Winona'],
          'Tribe': ['Bataknese', 'Javanese', 'Bataknese', 'Javanese'],
          'Town': ['Indramayu', 'Jakarta', 'Jakarta', 'Batam'],
          'Username': ['dan.iel', 'melissaaaa', 'vic.ky', 'weenonuhh']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in `csv` module.

```
import csv
myDict = {'Name':[],'Tribe':[],'Town':[],'Username':[]}

with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        myDict['Name'].append(row[0])
        myDict['Tribe'].append(row[1])
        myDict['Town'].append(row[2])
        myDict['Username'].append(row[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read('data.csv',names=['a','b','c','d'])
myDict={}
myDict['Name']=df.a
myDict['Tribe']=df.b
myDict['Town']=df.c
myDict['Username']=df.d
```

Comment: There are no column names for the `CSV` file

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas also.example like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

for row in df:
    myDict = {'Name':df[0].tolist(), 'Tribe':df[1].tolist(),
            'Town':df[2].tolist(),'Username':df[3].tolist()}

print(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a method you can do it an easy way using pandas. The plus point, it works for any kind of data frame, not just the data frame from the CSV file of your case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')    # read the csv file
result = df.to_dict('list')  # convert the dataframe to a dictionary with columns as key and values as list.
print(result)
```